# Asio async_read blocking when called inside it's handler

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm testing a little protocol design of mine and having trouble getting a continuous async_read to work. My idea was to create a generic read handler that outputs the received data (testing) and then checks it to perform protocol-defined actions.

This means that I am calling a new async_read from within this generic handler, which for some reason blocks and my handler never returns, blocking further execution of my program.

**The relevant code**

```
void handle_read_server(const asio::error_code&error_code, size_t bytes_transferred, void *adress)
{
    // [...]
    char HELO[4] = {'H','E','L','O'};
    if (*received.data() == *HELO)
    {
        cout << "[Protocol] got HELO";
        got_helo = true;
        short code_data;
        asio::async_read(socket_server, asio::buffer(&code_data, 2), asio::transfer_all(), std::bind(handle_read_server, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2, &code_data)); // This read is blocking my program to continue it's execution.
    }
}
```

**What I'm asking**

What is causing the function to block here? Is there anything I can do appart from having an async_read thread run all the time passing any received values to  a stream in the server?

Comment: `asio::buffer(&code_data, 2)` you are passing a `short` which is a temporary 2 bytes integer here, as a buffer to `asio::buffer`, this can't be good, you need a persistent buffer that will outlive `async_read` call

Comment: So that would mean a buffer declared outside of the handler, so some kind of generic vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async_* call does, in fact, not block.

You have Undefined Behaviour, by passing the address of a local variable into the async operation/completion handler.

You have to ensure the buffer's lifetime extends till after the completion. The natural way to achieve that would be to make the buffer a member of the enclosing class.

Comment: Oddly enough defining the buffer outside the scope of the handler does not solve the problem.

Comment: Why don't you show a SSCCE that exhibits the problem. In all likelyhood you have an other source of UB

Comment: Could the use of std::bind lead to the issue? I am unable to compile boost on my windows system, which is why I use the header-only asio variant.

Comment: Should not be a problem. Does the remote end ever close the connection? You ask to transfer all. Maybe you're looking at the wrong thing

Comment: Does transfer all not transfer until the buffer is filled, e.g. until 2 bytes have been received?

Comment: @ionree yes it does. I was just thinking along. Clearly there is something we're not seeing. (Remember the SSCCE thing. See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100291/discussion-between-sehe-and-ionree).

Comment: Oh, believe me you, I have googled the hell out of this. If I understand correctly, async_read only places an operation the asio's queue, where it is then executed upon calling io_service.run(). And, typing this, i just realized where the problem was. I have server and client in the same program (testing), and was calling io_service.run() to invoke the handler, which then attempted to do the second async_read, that had never gotten any data (yet). Grrr.

Comment: I don't remember suggest you didn't google enough? But it sounds like you found the problem. Either have separate io_services on separate threads for client/server, or share the same io_service, in which case everything can be happily on a thread.

Comment: That was the point, I was sharing the io_service. Calling io_service.run() just after sending "HELO" and before sending the rest of the data, I was in fact blocking further execution, not in calling async_read but in calling io_service.run(). I now removed said premature io_serive.run() and hope to code hapilly ever after.

Comment: Or you could send the rest of the data in response to the completion of sending "HELO". This is the usual pattern in asynchronous IO. Also, consider having the run() stay around with `io_service::work`